# Recursion in prolog, binding to variable

Tags: binding, recursion, prolog

I have a recursive clause that takes a 2 lists, in every recursion call I'm deleting one element from the list and binding this new list (with the element deleted) to a new variable.

This is done properly if I write this variable. But when I have a model it will backtrack making the last binding (the list i need) to that variable undone by the previous binding.

I tried to replicate the situation in this little piece of code:

```
test([],Test,Result).
test([H|T],Test,Result):-
    member(H,Test),
    delete(Test,H,Test1),
    write(Test1),
    write('\n'),
    test(T,Test1,Test1).
test([H|T],Test,Test1):-
    test(T,Test,Test1). 

?- test([1,2,3],[5,2,4,6,1],R).
```

I do understand the result should be in the head of the clause like this:

```
test([H|T],Test,Test1)....
```

But then only the first recursion call will succeed, something I don't want to.

Any clues of how to tackle this?

Also, i'm fairly new to prolog, just read some tutorials on internet and did simple exercises

Comment: Can you please try to clarify what you want your predicate to do ? It's unclear at the moment, to me at least.

Comment: Try to describe what are you expecting `?- test([1,2,3],[5,2,4,6,1],R)` to returns?

Comment: The predicate here is just nonsense really, just tried to recreate my other (bigger)clause.
What I want is a predicate deletes some elements in a list during a recursion. When I end the recursive that list I get in the end I which as a binding to the variable. 
I know what I'm doing wrong (every recursion gets an other binding), just no clue how to fix this.

Comment: So I give a list to the predicate. It will run through it and delete some elements. End list with the deleted elements is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter([], []).

filter([Head|Tail], [Head|Result]) :-
    sometest(Head),
    filter(Tail, Result).

filter([Head|Tail], Result) :-
    \+ sometest(Head),
    filter(Tail, Result).
```

Now, to see how it works, try to issue a `trace/0` call before you run your `filter/2` predicate, that'll detail the execution (in swi pl at least) :

Consider this predicate `sometest/1` :

```
sometest(N) :- N mod 2 =:= 0.
```

now let's trigger the trace mode :

```
?- trace.
true.
```

And now, let's call your predicate :

```
[trace] ?- filter([1, 2, 3], R).
   Call: (6) filter([1, 2, 3], _G522) ? creep
   Call: (7) sometest(1) ? creep
   Call: (8) 1 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (8) 1 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (7) sometest(1) ? creep
   Redo: (6) filter([1, 2, 3], _G522) ? creep
   Call: (7) sometest(1) ? creep
   Call: (8) 1 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (8) 1 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (7) sometest(1) ? creep
   Call: (7) filter([2, 3], _G522) ? creep
   Call: (8) sometest(2) ? creep
   Call: (9) 2 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 2 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Exit: (8) sometest(2) ? creep
   Call: (8) filter([3], _G597) ? creep
   Call: (9) sometest(3) ? creep
   Call: (10) 3 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (10) 3 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (9) sometest(3) ? creep
   Redo: (8) filter([3], _G597) ? creep
   Call: (9) sometest(3) ? creep
   Call: (10) 3 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (10) 3 mod 2=:=0 ? creep
   Fail: (9) sometest(3) ? creep
   Call: (9) filter([], _G597) ? creep
   Exit: (9) filter([], []) ? creep
   Exit: (8) filter([3], []) ? creep
   Exit: (7) filter([2, 3], [2]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) filter([1, 2, 3], [2]) ? creep
R = [2] ;
false.
```

If you take the time to understand what prolog does here, it's basically that : you run as long as you don't find a predicate to be true(the base case, here, `filter([], [])`), and then you build your list backwards depending on which path you took to reach this case. Here it means that if sometest was true, you add the `Head` in `Result`, if not, you don't.

Note that you need to use `\+ condition` (which means that the condition cannot be proven) in the second clause as I did, or use cut in the first as follows, else, a matching `Head` will still go through second clause during backtracking :

```
filter([], []).

filter([Head|Tail], [Head|Result]) :-
    sometest(Head),
    !,
    filter(Tail, Result).

filter([Head|Tail], Result) :-
    filter(Tail, Result).
```

Now, if you use swi-pl, note that you can directly use `include/3` to achieve what you want (it's certainly present in other implementations as well in this name or another) :

```
?- include(sometest, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], R).
R = [2, 4].
```

Hope it helped.